# WPFToolkit CheckComboBox width issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I'm using the CheckComboBox (from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)) in an app, and I'd like to make the "textBox" where it shows the selected items a bit wider, (in fact, I want it to fill all the CheckComboBox) but I'm don't have any idea about how to apply the styles.

[image: CheckComboBox with the problem]

Any help?

Thanks!

---

Current code

```
 <UserControl
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">
 <!-- ... -->
 <Label Content="Locale: "/>
 <xctk:CheckComboBox Name="LocaleSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Locales}" ValueMemberPath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLocales}" Margin="5 2 0 2" />
```

Comment: As I said, I have no idea about how to style inner parts of a control, so I haven't done anything yet...

I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: Did you try `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes, but it didn't worked as I expected. Anyway, I started playing with HorizontalContent="Stretch" and looking some slightly related questions on StackOverflow and came to a solution. I've added the answer, just in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it placing this into the UserControl.Resources, and applying the style to the CheckComboBox

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:CheckComboBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
<!-- ... -->
<xctk:CheckComboBox Name="LocaleSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Locales}" ValueMemberPath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedLocales}" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyle" Margin="5 2 0 2" />
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you can remove the `x:Key` attribute from the style, and make it apply to all `CheckComboBox` inside the container for which the style was declared.

Comment: I didn't even know you could add resources to a style; This fixed my issue, thanks!